# How is this sentence written correctly in maths? (sets)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, notation, solution-verification

A subfamily of $l$ sets $A_i$ with $1 \leq l < n$ is a "critical family", if its union contains exactly $l$ elements.

(Information so you know what these symbols mean: $X$ is a finite set and $A_1,A_2,..,A_n$ are subsets of $X$)

I would write it like that $$\left|\bigcup_{i=1}^{l} A_i\right|=l$$

I hope you can tell me because I'm using this definition in a presentation and I don't know if it's written correctly like that?

I'm not sure if I really need to use these cardinality symbols ||

Comment: It seems ok. Because you could call $\mathcal{A}$ the union of the sets $A_1,\dots, A_l$ and in this case you would write $|\mathcal{A}|=l$.

Comment: @Vajra Thanks for comment :) If I removed these | | cardinality symbols , I think it would be wrong because $l$ is some number and I couldn't set it equal to a set. But with cardinality symbols I can. Maybe this is a correct reasoning but I'm still not entirely sure ^^

Comment: Yes, you're talking about "number" of elements, so the symbol | | defines a natural number that, in your case, is $l$. Th fact is that you use the symbol | | with sets and the union of a finite number of open sets is still an open set...

Comment: When you write $\{A_i: i\in I\}$ you are saying you have a function  $f$ with domain $I$ but are preferring to write $A_i$ for $f(i).$ An index-set $I$ is often unnecessary. If $A$ is a family of sets then $\bigcup A=^{def}\cup_{a\in A}a .$ That is, any $x\in\bigcup A$ iff $x$ belongs to at least one member of $A.$